# Trouble rendering bootstrap-select in mustache template

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, mustache

I am having trouble using the bootstrap-select.
When I create a simple select in an html file, everything works as expected :

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option selected>Mustard</option>
    <option selected>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

The style is correctly applied from the bootstrap-select.min.css

But when I try to render it in a template, it doesn't apply the correct css/js.

```
<script type="template/text" id="template">
        <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
            <option selected>Mustard</option>
            <option selected>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>
        <table id="tblItems" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                ...
         </table>
</script>
```

In the console, I can see that the style is applied from bootstrap.min.css and not from the bootstrap-select.min.css

That's what I defined in the head :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Is that coming from the fact that the boostrap-select might not be loaded when the template is rendered?

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

I had to initialize the select after my template is rendered.

```
var template = $('#template').html();

var output = Mustache.render(template, {rows:context});

$("div").append(output);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Comment: What does selectpicker() do? (if you can add the code better).